# Reading names of files that need updating in svn into a batch file

Tags: svn, batch-file

Ok maybe the title isnt the best summation, its better for me to explain.

I understand the way to show which files need updating in svn is to use the `svn st -u` command and you will get a list of files like the following:

```
 O        4611   PanelAbility.xls
 O        4611   Figure.xls
 O        4611   Character.xls
    *     4611   GrowthBoard_1.xls
    *     4611   GrowthBoard_2.xls
    *     4611   GrowthBoard_3.xls
    *     4611   PoseTree.xls
 O  *     4611   Panel.xls
```

is there any way for me to isolate the output so I can read just the .xls filenames, then use those values as command line arguments?

Essentially what I need is a batch file that calls svn st -u, reads the filenames into a series of variables/an array, runs the update, then using the filenames runs a command line argument that reads these updated files into a database e.g

1) check for files that need updates

2) if any files need updating, read them into an array

3) update the working copy

4) for each filename in the array, run the command line to read it into a database

Maybe a batch file is inadequate for this, and I would need to write a script or a "real" program. If so what should I do?

I`m running a windows o/s.

Comment: Step uno `findstr /e .xls`... Other steps require a bit more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract and show you the list of filenames one at a time.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('svn st -u ^|find /i ".xls" ^|repl ".{17}(.*)" "$1" ') do (
    echo "%%a"
    pause
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to use a batch file in the end, but instead used something I'm more familiar with - python. Pysvn is a great module to use. I also used pycurl as after the svn update I needed to post a request to a build machine with all the filenames as parameters.